# Passing in `null` to Option[Int] Argument

Tags: scala

I have a function `foo`:

```
scala> def foo(maybeInt: Option[Int]) = maybeInt.map(_ + 5)
foo: (maybeInt: Option[Int])Option[Int]

scala> foo(Some(5))
res10: Option[Int] = Some(10)
```

However, I can pass in `null` to get a `NPE`:

```
scala> foo(null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
      ...
```

At compile-time, is there any way to avoid this error? Or are `null` checks simply required in Scala?

I would strongly expect the above code to fail a code review, yet I'd want the compiler to catch it.

Comment: Why pass `null` to a function that accepts `Option[Int]` (or ever)?

Comment: I would not ever pass in `null`, yet I want to know if/how the compiler can check for such behavior.

Comment: What do you want the compiler to catch? Check for what behavior? You can't prevent `null` from being passed anywhere.

Comment: The compiler can't possibly protect you from every possible exception you might throw. If you're not deliberately passing `null`, and the APIs you're working with aren't passing `null`, then what is there to worry about?

Comment: Like @LimbSoup said, you can design your code that way. Don't use `null` and if you depend on code that might return `null`, you can wrap the return value in an `Option`. `Option(null) == None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, and for Java interop, any reference type may be `null`. In the type system, `Null` is a subtype of anything deriving from `AnyRef`.

Conclusion: Simply don't use `null` values. There are very little reasons to do so in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can avoid it by using overload. If you add a `foo` method taking `Null` it should take precedence. It will still compile, though, so you have to add something else. I'd try an non-existent implicit. Something like this:

```
def foo(m: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = ???
def foo(m : Null)(implicit n: NonExistent): Unit = ???
sealed abstract class NonExistent
```

Note, however, that this won't protect you from *variables* containing `null`. There's no way to statically prevent that except using the @NonNull, which doesn't work well and has been deprecated.

The *real* answer is that any use of the word `null` is an error, unless you are calling Java. Let it throw a exception.